# Social Studio monthly mentions limit

Tags: marketing-cloud, social-studio, radian6

The social studio basic version limits to 20k the mention count. What is that referring to? is that the mention count of my brand that the platform would analyze?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, that is the number of your brand mentions (@brandname) **per month** your Social Studio will be able to capture/analyse and display on the wall for further engagement.